# Google Maps API: Get position over Sealevel

Tags: google-maps

is there a way to get the position over sealevel from a given position using the Google Maps API?

Any Help would really be appreciated!

Comment: also checkout this http://www.daftlogic.com/sandbox-google-maps-find-altitude.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think Google Maps does not provide such a function in its API. But there are **other free services** which integrate well into Google Maps:

- [TopoCoding](http://topocoding.com/) (example [here](http://freegeographytools.com/2007/altitudes-and-terrain-profiles-in-google-maps))
- [GeoNames.org](http://www.geonames.org/) (example [here](http://www.daftlogic.com/sandbox-google-maps-find-altitude.htm))
- [EarthTools.org](http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm) (example for [Birmingham, UK as XML result](http://www.earthtools.org/height/52.4822/-1.8946))

Answer (score 1):

Google now provide this service, checkout google.maps.ElevationResult object specification in the [reference documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html)